# django test client fails, but url works

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm having a strange problem with some unit tests, which are quite simple, but are failing. The strange thing is that this work with runserver, i.e, I can render the perfil_usuario view, but in unit tests this is failing with NoReverseMatch.

First of all, this my main urlconf:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^$", include("traxx.hotsite.urls", namespace="hotsite")),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^imperavi/', include('imperavi.urls')),
    url(r"^app/", include("traxx.sistema.urls", namespace="app")),
    url(r"^usuarios/", include("traxx.usuarios.urls", namespace="usuarios")),
    url(r"^notificacoes/", include("traxx.notificacoes.urls", namespace="notificacoes")),
    url(r"^clientes/", include("traxx.clientes.urls", namespace="clientes")),
)
```

My usuarios (4th url conf in main) urlconf is the following:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns("traxx.usuarios.views",
                       url(r"^perfil/(?P<id>\d+)/$", "perfil_usuario", name="perfil"),
                       url(r"^configuracoes/(?P<id>\d+)/$", "configuracoes_usuario", name="configuracoes"),
                       url(r"^login/$", "login", name="login"),
                       url(r"^logout/$", "logout", name="logout"),
)
```

This is the view:

```
def perfil_usuario(request, id):
    usuario = get_object_or_404(Usuario, pk=id)
    return render(request, "usuarios/perfil_usuario.html", {"usuario": usuario})
```

And this is the failing unit test:

```
class PerfilUsuarioViewTestCase(TransactionTestCase):

    """Testes para a view home"""

    def setUp(self):

        pass

    def test_get_perfil_usuario(self):

        usuario_fake = mommy.make(Usuario, nome_usuario="teste")

        c = Client()
        resposta = c.get(reverse("usuarios:perfil", kwargs={"id": usuario_fake.pk}))

        self.assertEqual(200, resposta.status_code)
```

The reverse call reverse("usuarios:perfil", kwargs={"id": usuario_fake.pk}) works just fine, outputing /usuarios/perfil/1/.

#### Call to reverse

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>> reverse("usuarios:perfil", kwargs={"id":1})
/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imperavi/views.py:1: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5

'/usuarios/perfil/1/'
```

I'm using Django 1.6.

#### Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/george/projetos/traxx/src/traxx/testes/usuarios/views.py", line 21, in test_get_perfil_usuario
    resposta = c.get(reverse("usuarios:perfil", kwargs={"id": usuario_fake.pk}))
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 473, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 280, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 444, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/george/projetos/traxx/src/traxx/usuarios/views.py", line 12, in perfil_usuario
    return render(request, "usuarios/perfil_usuario.html", {"usuario": usuario})
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 53, in render
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 169, in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 137, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 85, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 840, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 78, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 447, in render
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 433, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 509, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/george/projetos/.virtualenvs/traxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 429, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'perfil' with arguments '(None,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'usuarios/perfil/(?P<id>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: Could you show the full error traceback? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the traceback, `id` passed in `kwargs` is evaluated to `None`. This is why it is not matching the `usuarios/perfil/(?P<id>\\d+)/$` url pattern.

In other words `usuario_fake.pk` value is `None`.

UPD:

the problem was actually in the template which the traceback was complaining about.

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks for looking all this code. Sometimes we cannot see the most obvius things.

Comment: @George ok, I haven't personally used `model_mommy`, but a shot in the dark would be to replace `usuario_fake.pk` with `usuario_fake.id`..

Comment: I've tried just that. I've added print statements to the test, printing pk and id. Both output 1. I even hardcoded "1" for this test. The reverse method works just fine, check the updated question.

Comment: @George ok, thanks, so if you hardcode `1` the test works, right?

Comment: @George could you also try to use `self.client` instead of instantiating `Client` manually? `self.client.get(reverse("usuarios:perfil", kwargs={"id": usuario_fake.pk}))`

Comment: No, the reverse call works. I tried to use c.get with the result, but still fails. The self.client.get call fails too, with same exception.